# Allocate memory without declaring a type and then assign a struct type later

Tags: c

I can explicitly create a struct pointer to allocated memory no problem.

```
widget *p = malloc(sizeof(widget));
```

and then access members of `p` like `p->i`.
But in the following example of allocating memory without declaring a type, I get an error trying to access `i` because the type of pointer is `void` or `char` and not `struct`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char c[10];
    int i;
    double d;
} widget;

int main() {
    //two ways to do this. char was convention before void type was introduced

    void *p = malloc(sizeof(widget)); //base type void is not a structure or union
    //char * p = malloc(sizeof(widget));//base type char is not s structure or union

    widget w = {"abc", 9, 3.2};
    memcpy(p, &w, sizeof(widget)); //coerced to void * pointers
    printf("%d", p->i);// error here trying to access 

    return 0;
}
```

This example is from "Effective C" by Robert Seacord. Here is what the book says about the example.

> In either case the object pointed to by p has no type until an object
> is copied into this storage. Once this occurs the object has the
> effective type of the last object copied into this storage, which
> imprints the type onto the allocated object. In the following example,
> the storage referenced by p has an effective type of widget following
> the call to memcpy.

I tried casting `p` to a pointer to widget type but this made no difference.

I am probably misunderstanding or missing something. In the book the only difference is he uses a size variable in the example with no explanation as to what the value of the size should be when creating the `void *` pointer.

I assumed it should be of `sizeof(widget)` in order to hold a widget. On the `memcpy` line he actually uses `sizeof(widget)` in the book.

Also the comment `//coerced to void * pointers` is from the book and I don't know what it means. The rest of the comments are mine.

Can someone please explain to me why this is not working?

Update: Here are the attempts I made to cast `void *` to `widget *` after `memcpy`

```
//casting attempts
(widget *) p; //no change


widget *q = (widget *) p;
printf("%d", q->i); // works 

printf("%d", ((widget *)p)->i); //also works
```

Comment: *I tried casting p to widget type but this made no difference*. That should work. Please show the exact code you tried.

Comment: Specifically: `printf("%d", ((widget *)p)->i)`

Comment: Tip: `typedef struct widget { ... }` and then make a *local* variable `widget w` later on.

Comment: Both your "wrong value" cast attempts should work fine, and do: https://godbolt.org/z/8PvnEf.  Is there other code in your example that doesn't match what you've shown?  Is this a MRE?

Comment: Note that `(widget *) p;` by itself is a no-op, like writing `x+1;`.  It evaluates the expression, which is indeed of type pointer to `widget`, but then it does nothing with it.  In particular it does not change `p` any more than `x+1;` changes `x`.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting wrong value ? if so problem might be somewhere else [here](https://onlinegdb.com/YFujkaqG9) it works fine.

Comment: Sorry all, the 249 was because I printed out the sizeof widget at the top of the program. Updating now

Comment: So both of those methods of casting work. But I am wondering is it a implementation thing (different compilers or standard)? Is the book wrong or am I misunderstanding something? The book code specifically access p->i without any casting which is in line with my understanding of the quoted text from the book.

Comment: *the effective type of the last object copied into this storage, which imprints the type onto the allocated object*. On the face of it the book sounds plain wrong. A `void *` pointer doesn't magically become another type just by doing a `memcpy`. That makes no sense at all unless there is more to that quote.

Comment: The code in the book is wrong. It would be an exaggeration to say 5hat the description of what an "effective type" is is also wrong, since that explanation doesn't seem to exist. An SO comment is too short to really do justice to the subject; suffice it to say that "effective type" does not alter the language syntax. The member operators `.` and `->` respond to the declared type; a void* is a void* no matter what the effective type might be, and a void has no members.

Comment: "I tried casting p to widget type" mis-states what code `(widget *) p;` does .  That is a cast to `widget *` and so better stated as "I tried casting p to _a pointer to_ widget type".

Comment: Aside: less error prone alternative to `memcpy(p, &w, sizeof(widget));` --> `memcpy(p, &w, sizeof w);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The so-called “imprinting” of effective type is notional: It is used only as an abstract description to describe how compilers work or may work. No actual recording of the type is made in memory.

You must provide the type that is used to access the object, but writing expressions with that type. For example, it `p` is declared `void *p`, then the type of `p` is `void *` regardless of what has been stored at the address it points to, and `*p` will always be `void`, which cannot be used to access an object. You can convert `p` to `widget *` by using a cast, `(widget *) p`, and then the result of that expression has type `widget *`, and you can use it to access an object, as width `((widget *) p)->i`.

> `(widget *) p; //no change`

The cast operator merely produces a value; the result of `(widget *) p` is a value that can be used further in an expression, as in an assignment expression like `q = (widget *) p` or a `printf` like `printf("%d\n", ((widget *) p)->i);`. It does not make any change in `p`.